# Flutter - generic function typedef errror

Tags: dart, flutter

I am writing a base loadmore listview in flutter following the tutorial [building-a-social-network-with-flutter](https://github.com/fablue/building-a-social-network-with-flutter):

- Define a typedef function as a listview adapter, it return a widget for each item:

  ```
  typedef Widget WidgetAdapter<T>(T t);
  ```
- My base listview widget:

  ```
  class LoadingListView<T> extends StatefulWidget{

    ...

    final WidgetAdapter<T> widgetAdapter;

    ...

    @override createState() => new _LoadingListViewState();

  }
  ```
- My base listview state:

  ```
  class _LoadingListViewState<T> extends State<LoadingListView<T>> {

    ...

    List<T> objects = [];

    ...

    Widget itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {

      return widget.widgetAdapter != null ? widget.widgetAdapter(objects[index]);
          : new Container();
    }

  }
  ```
- In my UserList widget:

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget w;
  w = new LoadingListView<User>(
      request, widgetAdapter: adapt, pageSize: widget.pageSize, pageThreshold: widget.pageThreshold);
  return w;
  }

  Widget adapt(User user){
  return new UserItem(user); //return widget UserItem
  }
  ```

  And i am getting the error:

  ```
  type '(User) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Widget'
  ```

How to fix it. Please help me. Thanks you very much.

Comment: change your createState method to `@override State createState() => new _LoadingListviewState<T>()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem with createState() method in your StatefullWidget class.

Update your createState() method like this.

```
@override  
State createState() => new _LoadingListViewState<T>()
```